# How do I center a UL LI list in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html-lists, alignment, text-alignment

Take a look at:

http://liveharleystreet.phil-taylor.com/

And specifically the menu that appears first in the footer. In every other browser this menu is centered, but in IE9 it is ranged left.

How do I change my CSS to make it appear centered in IE9?

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the custom.css file with the developer tools of IE9 in the selector

```css
.footer .moduletablemenu ul li
```

**changing the display to inline and removing the float property**; that centers the footer in IE9. Seems you are having problems with the style loading depending on the browser.